# Cannot pass a list of Subnet IDs as parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to pass in a list of Subnet IDs to a Cloud formation template, but I get an error. What have I done wrong?

Parameter in template:

```
  ClusterSubnets:
    Description: Subnets, in the same VPC where cluster ec2 instances reside.
                Typically private.  Use mutiples, each in a different AZ for HA.
    Type: "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>"
```

Parameter snippet from json file:

```
  {
    "ParameterKey": "ClusterSubnets",
    "ParameterValue": [ "subnet-8fc8c4f7" ]
  },
```

Results In:
Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Parameters[1].ParameterValue, value: [u'subnet-8fc8c4f7'], type: type 'list', valid types: type 'basestring'

Answer (score 7):

I know this thread is a year old, an I am assuming you were using the aws cli to create the stack, but I was having the same issue and finally stumbled on the answer. Giving credit where its due:
https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2478#issuecomment-427167512

escape the "," with a backslash and it will solve the issue. In my case this was in a jekins job bashing out so I had to double backslash:

```
  sh "aws cloudformation create-stack  --template-url ${TEMPLATE} \
      --stack-name $NAME \
      --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM \
      --parameters ParameterKey=SecurityGroups,ParameterValue=\"$SG_GROUP2\\,$SG_GROUP1\"; \
  aws cloudformation wait stack-create-complete --stack-name $CLUSTER_NAME"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the ParameterValue using a comma-delimited list of the subnet IDs you want to include, without spaces. See the section under "list" here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html